# difference in structure of abstract factory

Tags: c++

I have written 2 types of codes for abstract factory: type1 and type2
type1 is what I have derived by going through websites in internet
but type2 is what according me should be a better convention

type1
First there is the base class of required end product. There is required base class of factories. Decide what the required brands of factories. Instantiate concrete class of them by derivation. Decide what are the common categories each brand of factories should provide. Then instantiate concrete of final products of each end product by derivation. But in main function , you are directly creating the factory object. There will be more maintainance required in such code.

```
  class Shoe
    {
    public:
        virtual void Detail() = 0;
    char make[2];
    int size;
    };

    class Shoe_B5:public Shoe //small
    {
    public:
        Shoe_B5()
        {
            strcpy(make,"B");
            size = 5;
        }
        void Detail()
        {
            cout<<"Shoe"<<make<<size<<endl;
        }
    };

    class Shoe_B6:public Shoe //medium
    {
    public:
        Shoe_B6()
        {
            strcpy(make,"B");
            size = 6;
        }
        void Detail()
        {
            cout<<"Shoe"<<make<<size<<endl;
        }

    };

    class Shoe_B7:public Shoe //large
    {
    public:
        Shoe_B7()
        {
            strcpy(make,"B");
            size = 7;
        }
        void Detail()
        {
            cout<<"Shoe"<<make<<size<<endl;
        }

    };

    class Shoe_B8:public Shoe //XL
    {
    public:
        Shoe_B8()
        {
            strcpy(make,"B");
            size = 8;
        }
        void Detail()
        {
            cout<<"Shoe"<<make<<size<<endl;
        }

    };

    class Shoe_RT5:public Shoe //small
    {
    public:
        Shoe_RT5()
        {
            strcpy(make,"RT");
            size = 5;
        }
        void Detail()
        {
            cout<<"Shoe"<<make<<size<<endl;
        }

    };


    class Shoe_RT6:public Shoe //medium
    {
    public:
        Shoe_RT6()
        {
            strcpy(make,"RT");
            size = 6;
        }
        void Detail()
        {
            cout<<"Shoe"<<make<<size<<endl;
        }

    };

    class Shoe_RT7:public Shoe //Large
    {
    public:
        Shoe_RT7()
        {
            strcpy(make,"RT");
            size = 7;
        }
        void Detail()
        {
            cout<<"Shoe"<<make<<size<<endl;
        }

    };


    class Shoe_RT8:public Shoe //XL
    {
    public:
        Shoe_RT8()
        {
            strcpy(make,"RT");
            size = 8;
        }
        void Detail()
        {
            cout<<"Shoe"<<make<<size<<endl;
        }

    };

    class Factory
    {
    public:
        virtual Shoe* createSmall() = 0;
        virtual Shoe* createMedium() = 0;
        virtual Shoe* createLarge() = 0;
        virtual Shoe* createXL() = 0;
    };

    class BataFactory: public Factory
    {
    public:
        Shoe* createSmall()
        {
            return new Shoe_B5;
        }
        Shoe* createMedium()
        {

            return new Shoe_B6;
        }
        Shoe* createLarge()
        {

            return new Shoe_B7;
        }
        Shoe* createXL()
        {

            return new Shoe_B8;
        }
    };


    class RedTapeFactory: public Factory
    {
    public:
        Shoe* createSmall()
        {

            return new Shoe_RT5;
        }
        Shoe* createMedium()
        {

            return new Shoe_RT6;
        }
        Shoe* createLarge()
        {

            return new Shoe_RT7;
        }
        Shoe* createXL()
        {

            return new Shoe_RT8;
        }
    };

    class Client
    {
    Factory* fac;
    Shoe* s;
    public:
        Client(Factory* factory)
        {
            fac = factory;
        }
        Shoe* Create(int num)
        {
            switch(num)
            {
                case 1:
                      s = fac->createSmall();
                      break;

                case 2:
                      s = fac->createMedium();
                      break;

                case 3:
                      s = fac->createLarge();
                      break;

                case 4:
                      s = fac->createXL();
                      break;

            }
        }
        void getDetails()
        {
            s->Detail();
        }

    };

int main()
{
    Factory * fac;
    if(condition)
        fac = new BataFactory;
    else
        fac = new RedTapeFactory;

    Client * c = new Client(fac);
    c->create(Size);
    c->getDetails();
}
```

differences in type 2
But in main function , you are creating the factory like in factory method. There will be less maintainance required in such code.

```
 class Factory
    {
    public:
        //produce allowed category of shoes
        virtual Shoe* createSmall() = 0;
        virtual Shoe* createMedium() = 0;
        virtual Shoe* createLarge() = 0;
        virtual Shoe* createXL() = 0;
        //produce allowed category of factories
        static Factory* CreateFactory(int num);

    };

    Factory* Factory::CreateFactory(int num)
        {
            switch(num)
            {
                case 1:
                    return new BataFactory;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    return new RedTapeFactory;
                    break;
            }
        }

int main()
{
    Factory * fac;
    switch(condition)
        {
             case 1:
                   fac = Factory::CreateFactory(1);
                   break;
             case 2:
                   fac = Factory::CreateFactory(2);
                   break;

        }
    Client * c = new Client(fac);
    c->create(Size);
    c->getDetails();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, you are using `new` and raw pointers for owned memory. This should never be done in C++. It will always create problems.

For example in your code you never delete this memory. This will lead to memory leaks. So, please do not use `new` and raw pointers for owned memorey. Use `````std::unique_ptr```` or similar in the future.

I also see case statements. This is also not the usual approach for modern variants of factories. You shoul use `std::map` with the selector as the key and a function pointer as the value.

You may add a little more flexibility, if you allow for constructed classes with different numbers of parameters by using variadic templates.

Please see here (one of many) possible solutions for a factory implementation.

```
`#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <any>


// Some demo classes ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct Base {
    Base(int d) : data(d) {};
    virtual ~Base() { std::cout << "Destructor Base\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Base\n"; }
    int data{};
};
struct Child1 : public Base {
    Child1(int d, std::string s) : Base(d) { std::cout << "Constructor Child1 " << d << " " << s << "\n"; }
    virtual ~Child1() { std::cout << "Destructor Child1\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Child1: " << data << "\n"; }
};
struct Child2 : public Base {
    Child2(int d, char c, long l) : Base(d) { std::cout << "Constructor Child2 " << d << " " << c << " " << l << "\n"; }
    virtual ~Child2() { std::cout << "Destructor Child2\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Child2: " << data << "\n"; }
};
struct Child3 : public Base {
    Child3(int d, long l, char c, std::string s) : Base(d) { std::cout << "Constructor Child3 " << d << " " << l << " " << c << " " << s << "\n"; }
    virtual ~Child3() { std::cout << "Destructor Child3\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Child3: " << data << "\n"; }
};



using UPTRB = std::unique_ptr<Base>;


template <class Child, typename ...Args>
UPTRB createClass(Args...args) { return std::make_unique<Child>(args...); }

// The Factory ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class Key, class Object>
class Factory
{
    std::map<Key, std::any> selector;
public:
    Factory() : selector() {}
    Factory(std::initializer_list<std::pair<const Key, std::any>> il) : selector(il) {}

    template<typename Function>
    void add(Key key, Function&& someFunction) { selector[key] = std::any(someFunction); };

    template <typename ... Args>
    Object create(Key key, Args ... args) {
        if (selector.find(key) != selector.end()) {
            return std::any_cast<std::add_pointer_t<Object(Args ...)>>(selector[key])(args...);
        }
        else return nullptr;
    }
};

int main()
{
    // Define the factory with an initializer list
    Factory<int, UPTRB> factory{
        {1, createClass<Child1, int, std::string>},
        {2, createClass<Child2, int, char, long>}
    };

    // Add a new entry for the factory
    factory.add(3, createClass<Child3, int, long, char, std::string>);


    // Some test values
    std::string s1(" Hello1 "); std::string s3(" Hello3 ");
    int i = 1;  const int ci = 1;   int& ri = i;    const int& cri = i;   int&& rri = 1;

    UPTRB b1 = factory.create(1, 1, s1);
    UPTRB b2 = factory.create(2, 2, '2', 2L);
    UPTRB b3 = factory.create(3, 3, 3L, '3', s3);

    b1->print();
    b2->print();
    b3->print();
    b1 = factory.create(2, 4, '4', 4L);
    b1->print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1 question, I understood everything, but what is int data{}; at the end of struct base?

Comment: can you also look at the following-> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59017834/error-in-printing-the-map-how-to-create-effectively-stdshared-ptr-from-stdan

Comment: I have seen int data; int data(0); but never seen int data{}

Comment: why are we returning UPTRB object from factory.create(); I think we should store it may be somewhere in map; and we can have an accesor method in factory that takes key and returns UPTRB object