# error in printing the map- how to create effectively std::shared_ptr from std:any?

Tags: c++, c++17

Here a base class is created. 3 child classes are created from that. These child classes will take variable type of arguments.
I understand 1st parameter to Factory is called when empty parameters and second when some parameters are passed.
2 methods add and create of factory are defined.
How to print elements of map "selector"? which simplifies to how to create effectively `std::shared_ptr<Base>` from `std:any`?

```
struct Base
{
    Base(int d) : data(d) {};
    virtual ~Base() { std::cout << "Destructor Base\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Base\n"; }
    int data{};
};

struct Child1 : public Base { 
    Child1(int d, std::string s) : Base(d) { std::cout << "Constructor Child1 " << d << " " << s << "\n"; }
    virtual ~Child1() { std::cout << "Destructor Child1\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Child1: " << data << "\n"; }
};

struct Child2 : public Base {
    Child2(int d, char c, long l) : Base(d) { std::cout << "Constructor Child2 " << d << " " << c << " " << l << "\n"; }
    virtual ~Child2() { std::cout << "Destructor Child2\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Child2: " << data << "\n"; }
};
struct Child3 : public Base {
    Child3(int d, long l, char c, std::string s) : Base(d) { std::cout << "Constructor Child3 " << d << " " << l << " " << c << " " << s << "\n"; }
    virtual ~Child3() { std::cout << "Destructor Child3\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Child3: " << data << "\n"; }
};

using UPTRB = std::unique_ptr<Base>;

template <class Child, typename ...Args>
UPTRB createClass(Args...args) { return std::make_unique<Child>(args...); }

// The Factory ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class Key, class Object>
class Factory
{
    std::map<Key, std::any> selector;
public:
    Factory() : selector() {}
    Factory(std::initializer_list<std::pair<const Key, std::any>> il) : selector(il) {}

    template<typename Function>
    void add(Key key, Function&& someFunction) { selector[key] = std::any(someFunction); };

    template <typename ... Args>
    Object create(Key key, Args ... args) {
        for(std::map<int, std::any, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::any> > >::iterator it = selector.begin(); it!= selector.end();it++)
        {
            cout<<"1st = "<<it->first;
            cout<<"2nd = ";
            std::any_cast<std::add_pointer_t<Object(Args ...)>>(selector[key])(args...)->print();
        }

        if (selector.find(key) != selector.end()) {
            return std::any_cast<std::add_pointer_t<Object(Args ...)>>(selector[key])(args...);
        }
        else return nullptr;
    }
    void print()
    {
        for(map<int,shared_ptr<Base>>::iterator it= selector.begin();it!=selector.end();it++)
        {
            cout<<"1st = "<<it->first;
            cout<<"2nd = "<<((it->second)->data)<<endl;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: One question per post please. You will find that "Please explain this code to me" kind of questions will most likely be closed here.

Comment: ok just how to print the map selector? editing...

Comment: What do you mean 'how to print map selector'. selector is a map Key -> std::any. There is not much to print if type of Key is not printable. Furthermore - `void add` method of Factory add a function. So selector value is not likely to be printable too.

Comment: The reason why you have `error: no match for ‘operator<<’... ` is because of line ` cout<<"2nd = "<<((it->second)->print())<<endl;` where you try to print a result of the print() call. Note that for you `Base` class `virtual void print()` - that is it is void - does not return results. So you can not print results of this call :)